# kdbg continue debugging keyboard shortcut

Tags: c++, c, ubuntu-14.04, kdbg

I am using kdbg for debugging.

```
> kdbg -v 
Qt: 4.8.6
KDE Development Platform: 4.13.3
KDbg: 2.5.4
>
```

The [official documentation](http://www.kdbg.org/manual/) is somewhat rudimentary. I am searching for a keyboard shortcut to continue running the program till it hits the next breakpoint. According to [this](http://math.hws.edu/eck/cs225/s02/kdbg.html) F7 should do. However running on Ubuntu F7 seems to always jumop at the end of the current function. How can I get kdbg to run the executable till the next breakpoint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I get kdbg to run the executable till the next breakpoint?

Hit F5.

Yes, I know, the menu does not change text to *Continue* or so, but the icon shows something like the *Play* icon that you know from your media software (or CD player, if you grew up in the past century) which also just continues, and does not start from the beginning.